# Installing Archlinx (Archcraft) alongside Windows 11 w/ EFI, but partition shows MBR?

Tags: linux, partitioning, efi

Installing Archlinux (Archcraft) alongside a pre-installed Windows 11..

I was expecting the Windows EFI system partition to show GPT, but viewing it within a live USB of Archcraft via fdisk -l reveals the Disklabel type to be dos, which is supposedly MBR? Is that reliable?

[fdisk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syrat.png)

Because when I cross-check it within Windows via diskpart, it shows an * under the GPT column, hence its GPT? Confused I am.

[diskpart image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY6oC.png)
[diskpart image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KXVk.png)

Yes, now I'm confused whether to select GPT or MBR for mounting the EFI partition in Archcraft installer inside the Windows EFI system partition.

Note I did disable Secure Boot in W11.

Referencing this for the dos = MBR distinction:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition#Mount_the_partition

Comment: See if this helps you. .....   https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows   ......   Windows 11 only supports 64-bit and a boot in UEFI mode from GPT disk.   Secure Boot should be ON